# Load a avro file in BigQuery - Unexpected type for default value. Expected null, but found string: "null"

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I need to transfer the result of this query to BigQuery, as you can see, I decode the data I get in Cloud Storage, I created an avro file to load it into a BigQuery table but I receive this error:

```
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-78860f4800c4> in <module>
    110 bucket_name1 = 'gs://new_bucket/insert_transfer/*.avro'
    111 
--> 112 insert_bigquery_avro(bucket_name1, dataset1, tabela1)

<ipython-input-8-78860f4800c4> in insert_bigquery_avro(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id)
    103         )
    104     print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
--> 105     load_job.result()
    106     print('Job finished.')
    107 

c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\job.py in result(self, timeout)
    695             self._begin()
    696         # TODO: modify PollingFuture so it can pass a retry argument to done().
--> 697         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
    698 
    699     def cancelled(self):

c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py in result(self, timeout)
    125             # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    126             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 127             raise self._exception
    128 
    129         return self._result

BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Unexpected type for default value. Expected null, but found string: "null"
```

This is the script process:

```
import csv
import base64
import json
import io
import avro.schema
import avro.io
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
import math
import os
import gcloud
from gcloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

try:
    script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
except:
    script_path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Keys\\key.json"

#Bigquery Credentials and settings
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = script_path

folder = str((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
bucket_name = 'gs://new_bucket/table/*.csv'
dataset = 'dataset'
tabela = 'table'

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("C:\\Users\\me\\schema_table.avsc", "rb").read())  

writer = DataFileWriter(open("C:\\Users\\me\\table_register.avro", "wb"), avro.io.DatumWriter(), schema)


def insert_bigquery(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('id','STRING',mode='REQUIRED')
    ]
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.field_delimiter = ";"
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')

#insert_bigquery(bucket_name, dataset, tabela)

def get_data_from_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    #Busca IDs
    query = """SELECT id FROM dataset.base64_data"""
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    return rows

a = get_data_from_bigquery()
length = len(a) 
line_count = 0

for row in range(length):
    bytes = base64.b64decode(str(a[row][0]))
    bytes = bytes[5:]
    buf = io.BytesIO(bytes)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(buf)
    rec_reader = avro.io.DatumReader(avro.schema.Parse(open("C:\\Users\\me\\schema_table.avsc").read()))
    out=rec_reader.read(decoder)
    writer.append(out)
writer.close()

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob("insert_transfer/" + destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name
    ))

upload_blob('new_bucket', 'C:\\Users\\me\\table_register.avro', 'table_register.avro')

def insert_bigquery_avro(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.AVRO
    time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning(type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY, field="date")
    job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')

dataset1 = 'dataset'
tabela1 = 'table'    
bucket_name1 = 'gs://new_bucket/insert_transfer/*.avro'

insert_bigquery_avro(bucket_name1, dataset1, tabela1)
```

I receive a CSV file in Cloud Storage like this:

[image]

And this script decode the register like this:

[image]

I want to create a routine to put the decoded information into BigQuery.

The schema file:

```
{
    "namespace": "transfers",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Transfer",
    "doc": "Represents the The transfer request",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string",
            "doc": "the transfer request id"
        },
        {
            "name": "date",
            "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            },
            "doc": "the date where the transaction happend"
        },
        {
            "name": "merchant",
            "type": "string",
            "doc": "the merchant who owns the payment"
        },
        {
            "name": "amount",
            "type": ["null", {
                "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 4,
                "scale": 2
            }],
            "default": "null",
            "doc": "the foreign amount for the payment"
        },
        {
            "name": "status",
            "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "transfer_status",
                "symbols": [
                    "RECEIVED",
                    "WAITING_TRANSFER",
                    "ON_PROCESSING",
                    "EXECUTED",
                    "DENIED"
                ]
            },
            "default": "DENIED"
        },
        {
            "name": "correlation_id",
            "type": ["null", "string"],
            "default": "null",
            "doc": "the correlation id of the request"
        },
        {
            "name": "transfer_period",
            "type": ["null", "string"],
            "default": "null",
            "doc": "The transfer period spec"
        },
        {
            "name": "payments",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": "string"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "metadata",
            "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": "string"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "events",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "name": "event",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "type",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "enum",
                                "name": "event_type",
                                "symbols": [
                                    "REQUEST",
                                    "VALIDATION",
                                    "TRANSFER_SCHEDULE",
                                    "TRANSFERENCE"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "amount",
                            "type": ["null", {
                                "type": "bytes",
                                "logicalType": "decimal",
                                "precision": 4,
                                "scale": 2
                            }],
                            "doc": "the original currency amount",
                            "default": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "date",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "long",
                                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
                            },
                            "doc": "the moment where this request was received by the platform"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "status",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "enum",
                                "name": "event_status",
                                "symbols": [
                                    "SUCCESS",
                                    "DENIED",
                                    "ERROR",
                                    "TIMEOUT",
                                    "PENDING"
                                ]
                            }
                        },

                        {
                            "name": "metadata",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "map",
                                "values": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "internal_metadata",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "map",
                                "values": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "error",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "record",
                                "name": "Error",
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "code",
                                        "type": ["null", "string"],
                                        "default": "null"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "message",
                                        "type": ["null", "string"],
                                        "default": "null"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "message",
                            "type": ["null", "string"],
                            "default": "null"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to include the following command to create an avro file and append the records that were decoded and try to upload this file to BigQuery but it didn't work. writer = DataFileWriter(open("C:\\Users\\me\\table_register.avsc", "wb"), avro.io.DatumWriter(), avro.schema.Parse(open("C:\\Users\\me\\schema_table.avsc").read())). Any suggestion?

Comment: The challenge is interesting but, why you don't simply perform a CSV with a schema? Do you have repeated field? If so, why you don't use JSON?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the feedback. This is a nested table that I receive from the information source provider. The mission I was given was to decode the information that intersects with the avsc schema and then play on BigQuery.  
I tried to convert the schema to json and the script result but was unsuccessful. What would you do in this script?

Comment: And yes, I have repeated field in this table.

Comment: Do you mean that you receive a AVRO file? Can you share an example that see if I can help you on this?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I include more details to clarify the idea!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I was able to create the avro file but I can't upload it now in BigQuery

Comment: Whats is the error now when you upload it in BigQuery after creating the avro file?

Comment: @SreeramNair "BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Unexpected type for default value. Expected null, but found string: "null""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `"default"` values from `"null"` to `null`.

[Reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1803).

Comment: can you help me about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090735/schema-avro-is-in-timestamp-but-in-bigquery-comes-as-integer/59096932#59096932