# Schema avro is in timestamp but in bigquery comes as integer

Tags: python, google-bigquery, schema, avro

I have a pipe that uploads avro files to bigquery, the configured schema seems to be ok, but BigQuery understands as an integer value and not a date field. What can I do in this case?

Schema´s avro - Date field:

```
{
  "name": "date",
  "type": {
    "type": "long",
    "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
  },
  "doc": "the date where the transaction happend"
}
```

Big Query table:

[image]

[image]

I tried using the code below but it simply ignores it. You know the reason?

```
import gcloud
from gcloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

def insert_bigquery_avro(target_uri, dataset_id, table_id):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.AVRO
    job_config.use_avro_logical_types = True
    time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning()
#    time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning(type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY, field="date")
    job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning
    uri = target_uri
    load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        dataset_ref.table(table_id),
        job_config=job_config
        )
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()
    print('Job finished.')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is intended since BigQuery by default ignores the logicalType attributes and uses the underlying Avro type instead. The Avro timestamp-millis logical type, for instance, is set to Integer in BigQuery.

To enable the conversion, set the `--use_avro_logical_types` to `True` using the command-line tool, or set the `useAvroLogicalTypes` property in the job resource when you call the jobs.insert method to create a load job. After this, your field `date` will be set as `Timestamp` type in BigQuery.

Take a look at the  [Avro logical types and BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types) doc to see all the ignored Avro logical types and how they'd be converted after setting that flag. This will also help you to decide the best Avro logical type for your fields.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried using the code below but it simply ignores it. You know the reason? (I include the script in the question)

Comment: can you help me?